# How to add an image to my Xamarin.Forms shared project's resources so that it can be used in both the Android and iOS projects?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms app for Android and iOS and I want to add images to my Xamarin.Forms shared project so that they are displayed in both the Android and iOS app.

This is how I added them currently:

[image: Xamarin.Forms Project]

This is how I'm referencing them in code and dynamically adding them to a Grid element:

[image: Code]

But I don't see the image loaded in the Grid when I run the app (with the Android emulator debugger).
I get the following errors in my Output window:

> [0:] Could not load image named: {0}: Images\Blue-1.png
>
> [0:] FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was
> invalid: File: Images\Blue-1.png

Do I need to add copies of the same images to the ModelT.Android and ModelT.iOS projects' resources too? (I thought the whole point of the main shared project was so I wouldn't have to do that?)

Comment: this is specifically addressed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any images in the shared project will need to be set to `EmbeddedResource` and the full path will need to be used for the source.

```
var image = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ModelT.Images.****Blue-1.png")
};
```

More info can be found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows) in the Embedded Images section.